# JAXB: code generation of elements with maxOccurs property set in the xsd file don´t get a set-method in the java class

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have a xsd file called `Person` with some elements. Some of the elements have both properties `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` set. Two lines in the xsd file could look like this.

```
<xsd:element name="NameOfElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:element name="NameOfAnotherElement" minOccurs="0">
```

In NetBeans I want to generate Java classes of this xsd file using JAXB.
All elements that just have the `minOccurs` property get both a set and a get method in the generated `Person` java file, but the elements that have both `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` properties set in the xsd file become a List. So the above xsd lines become this after the generation:

```
@XmlElement(name = NameOfElement)
protected List<Person.NameOfElement> nameOfElement;
@XmlElement(name = NameOfAnotherElement)
protected Person.NameOfAnotherElement nameOfAnotherElement;
```

The strange thing is that the variable `nameOfAnotherElement` gets both a set and a get method in the `Person` java class and `nameOfElement` only gets a get method.

Why don´t elements that become a `List<>` in the Java code get a set method (those elements that have both properties `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` set in the xsd)?

So my problem is that I cannot set the NameOfElement to a Person object because it misses a set method, but it contains a get method! Why is that so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have maxOccurs set to != 1, it can contain multiple instances of that element, so it becomes a list.

You should use the get method, and then add elements to that list. Something like this:

```
List<Person.NameOfElement> myList = doc.getNameOfElement();
myList.add(obj);
```

Edit: if you already have a list you want to use you can do the follwing:

```
doc.getNameOfElement().addAll(myList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin to force XJC generate setters for collections:

- https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Setters-Plugin

Comment: Where do I download the plugin? Or is it already installed in the JAXB package and I just need to activate it with `-Xsetters`?

Comment: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Downloads
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics/0.6.3/